# Sticky footer reveal

Tags: html, css, sticky

I've got sections that slide up over the header.
But I need the last section to reveal the footer.

It is possible to reveal the footer without JavaScript in a situation like this?

```css
html,
body,
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.header {
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.section1,
.section2,
.section3 {
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.section1 {
  background: orange;
}

.section2 {
  background: purple;
}

.section3 {
  background: red;
}

.footer {
  height: 10vh;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>

  <div class="section1">
    section 1
  </div>

  <div class="section2">
    section 2
  </div>

  <div class="section3">
    section 3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

[View on JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/hiyifuzuno/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: did you try adding a `z-index` below 10 to the footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your footer isn't showing up is because it has a lower z-index than the other sections. However, if you give your `.footer` class a higher z-index than the other sections, it will always show at the bottom because it has the style `position: fixed`.

One possible solution would be to give the footer the same z-index as the other sections, change its position to `relative`, and include it inside your `.container` class.

This would look like:

```css
html,
body,
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.header {
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.section1,
.section2,
.section3,
.footer {
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.section1 {
  background: orange;
}

.section2 {
  background: purple;
}

.section3 {
  background: red;
}

.footer {
  height: 10vh;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="section1">
    section 1
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
    section 2
  </div>
  <div class="section3">
    section 3
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/xekivep/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting :

```
z-index: 11;
```

Because you have z-index in the other container that's why you can't see the footer

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [`position:sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky).

> A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position
>   value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its
>   containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to
>   value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it
>   scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" until meeting
>   the opposite edge of its containing block.

However, consider the [browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).
At the time of this post, IE doesn't support "sticky" positioning.

Here's a demonstration:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  position:-webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  background: tomato;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
}

.section1,
.section2,
.section3 {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.section1 {
  background: orange;
}
.section2 {
  background: purple;
}
.section3 {
  background: red;
}

.footer {
  position:relative;
  height: 10vh;
  background: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  header
</div>
<div class="section1">
  section 1
</div>
<div class="section2">
  section 2
</div>
<div class="section3">
  section 3
</div>
<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```